# Java BigDecimal from String without decimal places but asume last two digits as decimal

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, bigdecimal

A have a String: "1234567"
I want to transfer this String to a BigDecimal with this format:
12345.67
--> The last two digets shall be treated as decimal places.

Is there any method for that, or do I have to use a resource consuming way like:

```
String numberUnformated = 1234567;
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(amount.substring(0,amount.length()-2)+"."+amount.substring(amount.length()-2))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("1234567") .movePointLeft(2):
```

Don't use doubles as suggested because you would certainly lose precision and with BigDecimal you won't. It's important when working with currencies.

Comment: Sounds good and maybe less resource consuming then a two times devide Operation. Thanks!

Comment: @GobiRan: `movePointLeft` simply adjusts the scale, so beats everything else.

Comment: yes, seems to me as well. Thanks to all for your good advices!

Answer (score 1):

You could divide it by 100 like this:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("1234567")
    .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100L));
```

Comment: Two divisions by 10 are slower (more overhead) than one division by 100, so why not `.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));` instead?

Comment: It is indeed valid, but `movePointLeft(2)` is IMO the only useful solution.

Comment: @Nicolas: what is the problem?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis never mind it is obviously just a waste of time